# Angular Material 2 themes - output single file or lazy load

Tags: css, angular, themes, angular-cli, angular-material2

*Disclaimer: There are a few questions on SO regarding CSS and debates over a single or multiple CSS files but I think this is a bit different*

I have a pretty big Angular 7 app using Angular Material 2 and I want to introduce themes. Each theme will be retrieved on user login (the theme is saved on the server and cannot be changed by the user).

**The question is mainly regarding whether it would be best to export a single CSS file** using top-level classes (body or app container) for each theme, replacing only classes that change for each theme **or lazy load a new css file on top of the main css file** with only the classes that are getting overwritten.

My biggest concern with the first option is getting a huge single CSS file. The current file is already around 300kb (unminified CSS is about 11k lines of code) and with themes ranging from 200-500 lines each and there could be 10+ themes, the file can easily get double or even triple that amount.

On the other hand, lazy loaded CSS might cause the user to download 2 smaller files but the implications might be worse. For example a lazy loaded CSS file needs to be exported with separate configs in Angular CLI and the name needs to be specific so it can be loaded from Angular on login which means caching might be an issue if something changes and also no versioning (eg. theme-blah-2.17.css) is also not possible in the name of the file. Possibly other implications that I cannot think of at the moment too.

Comment: i think according to your condition the best for you is to create one main stylesheet in which you can set all your common css and use it all over the site and multiple themes stylesheets to to change the colors and effects.this is the way we use for the sites with multiple themes.

Comment: @HUSSAIN thanks for the comment. So you mean specify the "main" default theme as an extra theme file? And how do you deal with lazy loading, file names and angular cli? Since this is the core part of the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how [material](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) handles themes.

Also, take a look at how teradata [Covalent](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/docs/theme) handles themes.